# iterating over children of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to iterate over an array of elements, and query the children of each

So far I've tried

```
$.each($("#new_shipment .package_dimensions .package_dimension"), function() {
      var amount = $(this).children('observe.amount').val()
      var weight = $(this).children('observe.weight').val()
      console.log(amount);
      console.log(weight);
```

HTML"

```
<h2>Packages</h2>
          <div class='packages form_pane'>
            <div class='package_dimensions'>
              <div class='dimensions_text'>
                <p>Dimensions in cm/kg</p>
              </div>
              <div class='labels'>
                <label>Amount</label>
                <label>Length</label>
                <label>Width</label>
                <label>Height</label>
                <label>Weight</label>
              </div>
              <div class='dimensions'>
                <div class='package_dimension' data-row-id='0' id='package_dimension_0'>
                  <div class="input string required shipment_package_dimensions_amount"><input class="string required observe amount" id="shipment_package_dimensions_0_amount" name="shipment[package_dimensions][0][amount]" type="text" /></div>
                  <div class='math_label'>×</div>
                  <div class="input string required shipment_package_dimensions_length"><input class="string required observe length" id="shipment_package_dimensions_0_length" name="shipment[package_dimensions][0][length]" type="text" value="15" /></div>
                  <div class='math_label'>×</div>
                  <div class="input string required shipment_package_dimensions_width"><input class="string required observe width" id="shipment_package_dimensions_0_width" name="shipment[package_dimensions][0][width]" type="text" value="12" /></div>
                  <div class='math_label'>×</div>
                  <div class="input string required shipment_package_dimensions_height"><input class="string required observe height" id="shipment_package_dimensions_0_height" name="shipment[package_dimensions][0][height]" type="text" value="10" /></div>
                  <div class='math_label'>&nbsp;</div>
                  <div class="input string required shipment_package_dimensions_weight"><input class="string required observe_weight" id="shipment_package_dimensions_0_weight" name="shipment[package_dimensions][0][weight]" type="text" value="10.0" /></div>
                </div>
                ......
             </div>
```

However, when I log the the result of amount and weight, I get undefined

Any ideas?

Comment: You're missing a dot in `.children('observe.amount')`. Try `.find('.observe.amount')`

Comment: Your inputs aren't the children of your selector. use `find` instead. Also, that's not the good way to use `.each` with a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing class selector(`.`) when class `observe` is used in `children()`. you should also use `.find()` instead of `.children()` as input elements are not immediate child of selected div :

```
$.each($("#new_shipment .package_dimensions .package_dimension"), function() {
  var amount = $(this).find('.observe.amount').val()
  var weight = $(this).find('.observe_weight').val()
  console.log(amount);
  console.log(weight);
 });
```

Comment: That will not work, the inputs aren't the children of the element